# Appium testing IOS app encountered "App is not installed error"

Tags: appium

Update to IOS V10 and XCode 8.0 on MacBook, and install the latest Appium server as 1.5.3. when testing app strange error displayed on Appium console as below, and i have install the app in IOS before start appium server.

[error screendump for appium server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox8pa.jpg)

i have try my testing app with below methods to confrim xcode instrument could run it:
1.  Open XCode, ensure our iPos App can be identified by Xcode and just installed normally on iPad. 
2.  Open Instruments, iPos can be opened by Instruments when click record.

is any one could give me suggestion? very appreciate for help.